# How do I get test coverage for Kotlin's class with only static constants (companion object consts)

Tags: testing, kotlin, test-coverage

I have a class in Kotlin with only static constants, a class with companion object containing only const val as we call it in Kotlin. It looks something like this..

```
package com.abc.xyz.util

class Constants {
    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT_VAL = 0
        const val USERNAME_FOR_ABC = "*"
    }
}
```

I wrote a method with just Assert.assertEquals like `Assert.assertEquals(Constants.DEFAULT_VAL, 0)` & `Assert.assertEquals(Constants.USERNAME_FOR_ABC, "*")` but it did not increase the test case coverage.

I want to know if there is a way I can cover this class under testing and increase my test coverage?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `companion object` to achieve the behavior you're looking for:

```
object Constants {
    const val DEFAULT_VAL = 0
    const val USERNAME_FOR_ABC = "*"
}
```

Regarding the test coverage you should consider that these are compile time constants. You don't increase your coverage with it, because it's not counted. You could have a look at your reports to find that this lines don't count.